# HTTP redirection

Tags: java, android, http, redirect

I wrote a method which should return a url after all redirection are done. but no matter what url I pass in the respone page is always 200 - OK, I've tried to use HttpPost but it returns always 404 - not found.

I used the following site to verify that the url should return 302/301 - redirect
http://www.internetofficer.com/seo-tool/redirect-check/

```
public static String redirect(String url){

    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
    DefaultHttpClient http_client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    try {
        HttpResponse response = http_client.execute(request);         
        Header[] headers = response.getHeaders("Location");

        if (headers != null && headers.length != 0) {
            String newUrl = headers[headers.length - 1].getValue();
            return redirectToGooglePlay(newUrl);
        } else {
            return url;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return url;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try turning off automatic redirect following - i.e. call `HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(http_client.getParams(), false);` before you call `http_client.execute(request)`.

Comment: thanks, it worked! (however I tried it before and it didn't work)